# How can I open a program always in 600x400?

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe, executable, resolution

How can I open a program always in 600x400? When I restart the computer I don't wanna configure again, how can I do this?

Observation: My resolution is 1920x1080 and I wanna open the program in 600x400 without change my resolution.

Sorry for my english, I don't speak very well this language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the program you want to open.

Some programs have a specific setting for this case.
Take a look on the documentation, or you can try to go to Regedit and look for the Key of program that you want to start with 600x400.
In the Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\(CompanyName)\(SoftwareName)`
Normally there is some settings about size of the window.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To change your display resolution from the command line - try the free `nircmd.exe` from http://www.nirsoft.net/